# Error using python Requests in an Azure VM

Tags: python, python-requests

When I run the following code in an Azure VM:

```
import requests

url = 'https://apidatalake.tesouro.gov.br/ords/siconfi/tt/rreo?an_exercicio=2022&nr_periodo=1&co_tipo_demonstrativo=RREO&no_anexo=RREO-Anexo%2003&id_ente=1100205'

requests.get(url)
```

It get that error:

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apidatalake.tesouro.gov.br', port=443): 

Max retries exceeded with url: 

/ords/siconfi/tt/rreo?an_exercicio=2022&nr_periodo=1&co_tipo_demonstrativo=RREO&no_anexo=RREO-Anexo%2003&id_ente=1100205 

(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa9a7352dc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: 

[Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

My security rules are:
[image]

When running in my local machine I got `<Response [200]>`. but using an Azure's VM, not.

python version >= 3.8
requests == 2.28.1

Comment: Well, trying to access that URL fails for me too (both locally from Finland and on [isitdown](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/apidatalake.tesouro.gov.br?proto=https)), so it's probably not on Azure's end but the server's. It might be blocking connections from outside Brazil, who knows.

Comment: Thanks for ur efforts. I've set a vpn with a brazilian IP and still without success...